# Flutter icons not centred in Iconbutton and alignment does nothing

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

The icons need to be centred within the Icon buttons otherwise when the two are centred together in the middle of the row, they appear slightly off centre to the right.

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left,
          color: Color(0xFFF89CC0), size: 42),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    IconButton(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right,
          color: Color(0xFFF89CC0), size: 42),
      onPressed: () {},
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```

I have `alignment` parameters set which as you can see in the screenshot are completely ignored:

[image]

How can I get them to be in the centre of their button?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that `IconButton`s have a default padding, so do it like this:

```dart
return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left, color: Color(0xFFF89CC0), size: 42),
          onPressed: () => {},
        ),
        IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Color(0xFFF89CC0), size: 42),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: I literally just found this out myself and came back to delete my question! Good work though anyway. I didn't expect this because every widget I came across so far has no default padding.

Comment: it's worth checking the constructors for these Widgets, lots of them have default values.

Comment: If anyone stumbles on this question, here's the official documentation on `Aligning Widgets` - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#aligning-widgets

Comment: @Sandeep Chayapathi Alignment is no use here, it was caused by padding. There was nothing wrong with the alignment.

Comment: This "hidden" padding was killing me until I found this answer. Gonna use the padding removal on all my future IconButtons. Makes life so much easier.

Comment: also working awesome in 2021, flutter 2.2.3! Thank you [:

Comment: Okay, so after getting crazy over my *icon not centering in its container* and the *padding not setting to 0*, I found out that the problem was coming from the `arrow_back_ios` icon I was using. I replaced it with `arrow_back_ios_rounded` and it works just fine (even if its still doesn't look quite perfectly centered)... i dont know whats the problem with this non-rounded IOS logo.

Comment: Ha! Tricky detail! Just saved me quite some time, thank you!